# NullPointerException in my unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

The first function throws `NullPointerException`, why does this happen? The second function doesn't have any problems.

[UrlShortenerTests.Java](https://github.com/pablooli/UrlShortener2014/blob/master/oldBurgundy/src/test/java/urlshortener2014/web/rest/UrlShortenerTests.java)

```
//Test de redireccion si la url corta existe
@Test
public void thatRedirectToReturnsTemporaryRedirectIfKeyExists()
        throws Exception {
    when(shortURLRepository.findByKey("someKey")).thenReturn(new ShortURL("someKey", "http://example.com/", null, null, null,
            null, 307, true, null, null));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/l{id}", "someKey")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isAccepted());
}

//Test de redireccion si la url corta no existe
@Test
public void thatRedirecToReturnsNotFoundIdIfKeyDoesNotExist()
        throws Exception {
    when(shortURLRepository.findByKey("someKey")).thenReturn(null);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/l{id}", "someKey")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

Stack trace:

```
test.java.urlshortener2014.web.rest.UrlShortenerTests > thatRedirectToReturnsTemporaryRedirectIfKeyExists FAILED
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException at UrlShortenerTests.java:74
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at UrlShortenerTests.java:74
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace of your exception

Comment: add trace and link to code

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code, you must mock all the injections in `UrlShortnenerOldBurgundy`. That includes `WorkRepositorySponsor` which is invoked in line 58 of your class `UrlShortnenerOldBurgundy` and causes the exception. Just add in `UrlShortenerClass`:

`@Mock WorksRepositorySponsor worksRepositorySponsor;`

Comment: Please, mark this answer as the solution to your problem :-)